# Google Script - How to generate template when cell within a range is modified?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I hope everybody is fine in those times

Posting this message to have some help on a tool I'm working on.
I'm very new to this, and my questions might be syntax / simple logic issues, as I lack the scripting basis

Here is what I'd like to do :
[image]

When cells in AC column are ticked (modified), I'd like my script to generate a template, and fill in that template with data A, B, C from the corresponding row that has been modified in AC column

So 3 steps here :

- 1 => When cells in AC columns are ticked (modified), I'd like my
  script to
- 2 => to generate a template
- 3 => fill in that template with data A, B, C from the corresponding
  row that has been modified in AC column

As for now, I'm stuck trying to make 1 and 2 work together.
3 might be another post if I don't find any solution

So here is the code for the onEdit function.
It is working. When I tick a cell in AC clumn, I get a "COOL" alert. (I've found this on Stackoverflow)

```
function onEdit() 

{
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var editRange = sheet.getActiveRange();
  var editRow = editRange.getRow();
  var editCol = editRange.getColumn();
  var range = sheet.getRange("AC3:AC31");
  var rangeRowStart = range.getRow();
  var rangeRowEnd = rangeRowStart + range.getHeight();
  var rangeColStart = range.getColumn();
  var rangeColEnd = rangeColStart + range.getWidth();
  if (editRow >= rangeRowStart && editRow <= rangeRowEnd 
      && editCol >= rangeColStart && editCol <= rangeColEnd){
        
       SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('COOL')

      }
}
```

Here is the code for GenerateTemplate, which is working as well

```
function GenerateTemplate() {

 var documentId = DriveApp.getFileById('XXXXXXXXXXXXXX').makeCopy().getId() ;

 DriveApp.getFileById(documentId).setName('CONTRACT_2021_V2');

 var body = DocumentApp.openById(documentId).getBody() ;
 
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet() ;
 var range = sheet.getRange(3,5);
 var data = range.getValue() ;

 body.replaceText('##Nom##' , data) ;
}
```

What I'd like to do is the articulate both functions.

I've tried several ways, but never succeeded.
Following the "if" statement, I've tried to add the GenerateTemplate function, but it doesn't seem to work

```
function onEdit() 

{
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var editRange = sheet.getActiveRange();
  var editRow = editRange.getRow();
  var editCol = editRange.getColumn();
  var range = sheet.getRange("AC3:AC31");
  var rangeRowStart = range.getRow();
  var rangeRowEnd = rangeRowStart + range.getHeight();
  var rangeColStart = range.getColumn();
  var rangeColEnd = rangeColStart + range.getWidth();
  if (editRow >= rangeRowStart && editRow <= rangeRowEnd 
      && editCol >= rangeColStart && editCol <= rangeColEnd){
        
       GenerateTemplate()

      }
}
```

I've also tried to put both functions on the same page. But still no success :

```
function GenerateTemplate() {

 var documentId = DriveApp.getFileById('XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX').makeCopy().getId() ;

 DriveApp.getFileById(documentId).setName('CONTRACT_2021_V2');

 var body = DocumentApp.openById(documentId).getBody() ;
 
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet() ;
 var range = sheet.getRange(3,5);
 var data = range.getValue() ;

 body.replaceText('##Nom##' , data) ;
}

function onEdit() 

{
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var editRange = sheet.getActiveRange();
  var editRow = editRange.getRow();
  var editCol = editRange.getColumn();
  var range = sheet.getRange("AC3:AC31");
  var rangeRowStart = range.getRow();
  var rangeRowEnd = rangeRowStart + range.getHeight();
  var rangeColStart = range.getColumn();
  var rangeColEnd = rangeColStart + range.getWidth();
  if (editRow >= rangeRowStart && editRow <= rangeRowEnd 
      && editCol >= rangeColStart && editCol <= rangeColEnd){
        
       GenerateTemplate()

      }
}
```

When I click "execute", my drive do get updated with a new copy of the template, correctly named. But nothing happens when I tick a cell in AC column.

If someone could help me making those 2 functions work together, that would be great

Best,

Comment: What output do you get in the executions window of script.google.com ? As per below answer, try renaming the onEdit to something else, and then INSTALL the onEdit trigger (can be done from the project screen, on the left "Triggers")

Comment: I installed the trigger via the specific windows in google script and it worked !

Thank you very much. Script is working now.

Now, trying to work on step 3 of my tools :)

Best,

Answer (score 1):

onEdit is a simple trigger.

Simple triggers cannot access services that require authorization.

Drive service (DriveApp) requires authorization => you can't call it from onEdit.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#restrictions

PS: I think this is the cause of your problem, if you post an exact error message you are getting, then I will be able to confirm that.

Comment: Hello Milan

Thank you so much for getting me on the right tracks. 
Authorization was the issue. 

I installed the trigger via the specific windows, and it worked !

Answer (score 1):

So, for other people, here is how it worked

Thx again to Milan and iansedano

Trigger can't launch access services that require authorization.
My tool goes through DriveApp, which is why the trigger wasn't working.

Script is working. But, for the trigger to work, you need to install it, through the specific windows in google script.

Here are the pictures :

[image]

then, choose your function

Thx again !
Kind regards

[image]